# Semantics of `%time` timestamp in `rostopic echo -p` from bagfile?

Tags: ros, rosbag, ros-kinetic, timestamp, rostopic-echo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I print the topic data using `rostopic echo -p -b filename.bag /topic_name`, there are two timestamps in the output. One comes from the header of the message (third column: `field.header.stamp`), one comes from somewhere else (first column: `%time`). Both have slightly different values, e.g.

- `%time`: 1552649896239792539 (2019-03-15 11:38:16.239793),
- `field.header.stamp`: 1552649894321638000 (2019-03-15 11:38:14.321638)

I didn't find documentation about the first timestamp `%time`. Is it assigned by rosbag to reflect the time of recording?

In this case, this would indicate that the message was recorded almost two seconds after the timestamp in the header indicates. Would it be reasonable to make inferences about the latency on the topic like this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/319414/semantics-of-%60%time%60-timestamp-in-%60rostopic-echo--p%60-from-bagfile?/) by [moooeeeep](https://answers.ros.org/users/27965/moooeeeep/) on ROS Answers with karma: 194 on 2019-03-25

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Reamees](https://answers.ros.org/users/36207/reamees/) on 2019-03-25**:
You have mostly answered the question already. The first time value is when rosbag received the message. About making inferences about latency based on the time differences. There are other factors you need to account for. For example if you are using more than one computer and are not synchronizing the clocks then you can get quite a big time difference from that. So I would say if you want to profile latency, then do that with tools designed to do that and once you know what the values are with the other factors taken into account you could make some assumptions based on the difference in the timestamps. If I would see a time difference of 2 seconds my first assumption would be  that the clock on the publishing computer is 2s behind the recording computer, not that latency is 2s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Is it assigned by rosbag to reflect the time of recording?

Comments given [here](https://answers.ros.org/question/82091/how-to-associate-rosbag-time-with-data/?answer=82331#post-id-82331) and [here](http://wiki.ros.org/rosbag/Cookbook#Rewrite_bag_with_header_timestamps) indicate that this is indeed the case.

> Would it be reasonable to make inferences about the latency on the topic like this?

This seems reasonable, at least from the point of view of the rosbag instance that has recorded the messages.

---

Originally posted by [moooeeeep](https://answers.ros.org/users/27965/moooeeeep/) with karma: 194 on 2019-03-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1